# self executing anonymous click function in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, self-executing-function

I need a click function in a for loop, so every id element is clickable. But I also need the i in the click function, that's why I thought a self executing anonymous function would be the best way to do so. But for some reason this is not working, maybe because the click function doesn't allow me to forward a parameter? What have I done wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {     
        $("#item-" + i).click(function(idx) {
           alert(idx);
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: event is always passed as first parameter of event handler. Anyway, you shouldn't use any loop here. Instead use class as selector or to set only one handler, delegate event. If idx is supposed to be the ID of clicked element, `this.id` will return it

Comment: Sometimes questions with so little code you'd think it would be easier to answer, but when many things go wrong I don't even know where to start... Skip.

Comment: I need this for loop anyway, I just abstracted it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self executing function must return a `function`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {
    $("#item-" + i).click(function(indx){
        return function(){  //must return a function
           alert(indx);
        }
    }(i));
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HuHXr/

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, using bind() javascript method:

```
for (var i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {
    $("#item-" + i).click(function(indx){
           alert(indx);
    }.bind($("#item-" + i)[0],i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {
   (function(i){  
        $("#item-" + i).click(function(idx) {
           alert(idx);
        });
   })(i);
}
```

Also note that `idx` is the event object.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DRLx/

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {     
    $("#item-" + i).click(clickFunctn);
}

function clickFunctn(obj){
    var i=$(obj).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    alert(i);
}
```

In this way you will optimize the code and your 'i' will be with you as well, and all items are clickable. And you are just binding one handler function.